# Get position and size of an object in a binary image

Tags: opencv, javacv, object-detection

Does someone have an idea to get the size and the position from an object? The Object is detected in a binary image with white pixels:

For example: Detected / Original

http://ivrgwww.epfl.ch/supplementary_material/RK_CVPR09/Images/segmentation/2_sal/0_12_12171.jpg
http://ivrgwww.epfl.ch/supplementary_material/RK_CVPR09/Images/comparison/orig/0_12_12171.jpg

I know about the `CvMoments`- Method. But I don't know how to use it in this case.

By the way: How can I make my mask more clearly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple algorithm:

1. Delete small areas of white pixels using morphological operations (erosion).
2. Use `findContours` to find all contours.
3. Use `countNonZero` or `contourArea` to find area of each contour.
4. Cycle throught all points of each contour and find mean of them. This will be the center of contour.

Answer (score 1):

If the object is tree, you should delete small areas by using morphology as Astor written.

Alternative of finding mass, and mass center is using moments: 
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=moments#moments

m00 as doc says is mass

There are also formulas for mass center.

This approach works when only your object remains on image after segmentation.